# Squircle with Java Canvas in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, canvas, shapes

I was asked to work on this shape called the Squircle. It is very similar to a rounded rectangle or square with rounded corners. However that's not the desired shape. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey... were you able to make squircle?

Comment: Yes, I can send you the link to my project if you want.

Comment: Mate, I would love to check it out. Here is my email :  mirmuhsin.sodiqov@gmail.com. Thanks

Comment: Just answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with my own solution, and today is a very simple library, here's the link. 
https://github.com/MicroRJ/android_superellipse

Here are a few sample images of my particular output.

[image]

[image: Squircles]

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Shape Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and set corner radius.

Comment: That's not a squircle still